# Grails 3.0 and Spring Security Error

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-3.0

In my build.gradle I added this line of code

```
 dependencies {

    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.3"

   }
```

Then when I try to use it

```
    import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

    @Secured('ROLE_ADMIN')
     class SecureController {
def index() {
    render 'Secure access only'
}
```

It "cannot resolve the symbol springsecurity"
I get the error

```
 Error:(5, 1) Groovyc: unable to resolve class Secured ,  unable to find class for annotation
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Build.gradle **** EDIT

This is the whole build.gradle file

```
    buildscript {
    ext {
    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
}
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
    classpath 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.5.0'
    classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate:4.3.10.5"
       }
   }

plugins {
id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "0.5.4.RELEASE"
}

  version "0.1"
  group "securityrolesspring"

    apply plugin: "spring-boot"
   apply plugin: "war"
   apply plugin: "asset-pipeline"
   apply plugin: 'eclipse'
   apply plugin: 'idea'
   apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-web"
   apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-gsp"

  ext {
 grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
       gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
       }

      assets {
       minifyJs = true
       minifyCss = true
      }

 repositories {
       mavenLocal()
maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
```

}

```
  dependencyManagement {
imports {
    mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
}
  applyMavenExclusions false
      }

dependencies {
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.3"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"

compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate"
   compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
   compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
   compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"

   runtime "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline"

  testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
  testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"

      // Note: It is recommended to update to a more robust driver    (Chrome,        Firefox etc.)
testRuntime 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.44.0'

console "org.grails:grails-console"
 }

      task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
       gradleVersion = gradleWrapperVersion
}
```

Comment: did you add compile dependency to existing dependencies block or you created new dependencies block with just this line ?

Comment: Existing dependency block, does this make a difference @droggo

Comment: If existing it should be fine. Try to compile the project using gradle instead of IDE. for example `gradlew classes` in project folder. If error is the same, can you provide whole build.gradle ?

Comment: How do I compile the project just using gradle? Im kinda new to this @droggo

Comment: And yes Ill update now with whole build.gradle @droggo

Comment: You should have `gradlew.bat` or `gradlew` files in your project folder, just open this folder using terminal and execute `gradlew classes`

Comment: Im sorry but I'm not sure how to execute that, could you please give me a few more detailed steps. Im using windows as well thanks @droggo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102594/discussion-between-droggo-and-hat-to-the-back).

Comment: Hi yes I am on the chat thanks @droggo

Comment: I added to the discussion again @droggo

Answer (score 0):

after 'apply plugin: "war"' add a line that says:
apply plugin: "maven"

in your repositories section, after "mavenLocal()" add a line that says:
mavenCentral()

this last recommendation is just cosmetic, but I would move your line:
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.3"

and place it after the 
 compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding" line.  it's good form to keep the initial set of grails dependencies pretty much as they are from the initial 'grails create-app' command.  the exception to this rule is if you want to replace the logback logging with something else, but that's another story.

finally, you could also change your spring-security-core dependency to version 3.0.4 which is out now.

Answer (score 0):

Spring security core has been updated the package location for @Secured Annotations. I use Grails 3.2.3 and Spring Security Core 3.1.1 int my project and works well. The following is the configuration the I used and is working as was in previos version of spring security core and Grails (2.X).

For installation, you have to add the entry in the dependencies block if your **build.gradle** file. Details in the oficial documentation for [installation section for Spring Security Core](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#installation)

```
dependencies {
   ...
   compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1'
   ...
```

To use the secured annotations in your controller, there were updates on the import (org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured) package and the @Secure annotation you have to assign to "value" the security statement you want to do. For example the annotation for @Secured('ROLE_ADMIN'), have to change like in the following example.

```
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured

@Secured(value=["hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"])
class SecureController {
    def index() {
    render 'Secure access only'
}
```

Detailed configuration are in the oficial documentation page, [updates for secured annotation in version 3](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#secured-annotation), and how to [define secured annotations](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#securedAnnotations).

Answer (score 0):

By importing

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured
```

you will be able to resolve your problem.

It will again say that it cannot resolve symbol "Secured" but you need to ignore it because the code will run completely according to your expectation.